# How do I make several pull request of one project?

Tags: git, github

Good day everyone,

I've forked a project on a github and would like to make a several pull requests for open source project. This is my first time, so I need an advice )))

What needs to be done:
1. (done) Fork a project;
2. (done) Create a feature and make a pull request (feature will wait for approval);
3. Take an initial copy of the project (as on step 1);
4. Create one more feature and another pull request.
5. Take an initial copy of the project (as on step 1);
6. Create one more feature and another pull request.

I do not understand steps from 3 to 6.
I.e. how can I maintain several copies of the project while making new features using github?

Thanks for advices,
Gennadiy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create branches for other features. You can branch from initial revision of your master branch, before you have done changes for the first feature.

I assume you did your first feature in `master` branch. That's fine, just make other features in different branches.

Answer (score 0):

For step 3 to step 6:

1. Create a new branch for your forked repo
2. Implement the changes you made in the new branch
3. Push the changes you made to the branch to your forked repo on GitHub
4. Create PR to the main repo with your branch on the forked repo.